# PHP setting to enable <?=

Tags: php, php-shorttags

I just upgraded my WAMP.

A lot of my code used to use `<?=$variable?>` for a quick echo statement. Does anyone know the php setting to turn this back on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in php.ini

Answer (score 2):

In PHP.ini, set short_open_tag = 1

Answer (score 2):

Set your short_open_tag to 1 inside your php.ini

Answer (score 1):

In php.ini this variable is called `short_open_tag`

Check this php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php for turning this ON.